# noncontiguous access of Armadillo matrix columns

Tags: r, matrix, rcpp, armadillo

I have the indices of a matrix stored in a list, and I want to access these columns in Rcpp.

```
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppArmadillo)
cppFunction('arma::mat tmp(arma::mat mat1, List list1) {
            arma::mat mat2=mat1.row(1);
return mat2.cols(as<arma::uvec>(list1[1]));

            }',depends = "RcppArmadillo")
```

However, the above function will cause a fatal error ("R sessions Aborted"). e.g.,

```
tmp(matrix(1:4,2),list(list(c(0))))
```

A similar function in pure rcpp will return this error.

```
note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Rcpp::Vector<19, PreserveStorage>::create<Rcpp::traits::named_object<arma::subview_row<double> >, Rcpp::traits::named_object<arma::subview_elem2<double, arma::Mat<unsigned int>, arma::Mat<unsigned int> > >, Rcpp::traits::named_object<Rcpp::internal::generic_proxy<19, PreserveStorage> > >' requested here
```

From this [documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#subcube), I should be able to access these columns via `arma:uvec`.

```
X.cols( vector_of_column_indices )
```

I'm not sure why it still asks me to use this format `X.cols( first_col, last_col )`.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The question is not particularly clear (and may benefit from some editing / clarification) but here are some key points:

- the memory model for R as well as as countless other applications is simple as requires *contiguous* memory for a vector
- a matrix is really just a vector with two-dimensional indexing so the *same holds*: contiguous memory is needed
- lists in R a different from matrices as they really are a list of columns
- same for data.frames which are, simplyfying somewhat, subclassed lists

So there are things you can, and cannot do.  The [Armadillo documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) is good and can help in stacking and combining parts of vectors into larger ones.

*Edit:*  Here is a very simple example that shows how to address this. Because Armadillo clearly wants a `matrix` to subset from, and a `uvec` with indices we ... simply give it a matrix and a vector of (unsigned) ints (which RcppArmadillo maps for us).  So you main issue really is how you go from the `List` to the uvec --- which does not work in the form that you have. I would recommend being more explicit in how you create the vector and properly instantiate one.

#### Code

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat subsetOfMatrix(arma::mat X, arma::uvec v) {
  return X.cols(v);
}

/*** R
M <- matrix(1:16,4,4)
subsetOfMatrix(M, c(0L, 2L))
*/
```

#### Output

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/64998018/answer.cpp")

R> M <- matrix(1:16,4,4)

R> subsetOfMatrix(M, c(0L, 2L))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    9
[2,]    2   10
[3,]    3   11
[4,]    4   12
R>
```